# Building C# with mono, can't find 'Regex.IsMatch' field

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to use xbuild from mono to compile my C# web application. I keep running into this error:

```
Field 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch' not found.
```

The only thing that I've been able to find about this error is to add 'System' as an assembly reference in the csproj file which I already had there. I also tried installing the 'System.Text.RegularExpressions' NuGet package and putting an assembly reference of 'System.Text.RegularExpressions' in the csproj file. Neither of those worked.

One thing I should note here. This error only gets thrown in my test library. I can build everything else fine without the tests but I need to be able to build the tests as I'm trying to set up CI that runs the tests. The tests are using NUnit.

Here's the data for what I'm using:

```
XBuild Engine Version 14.0
Mono, Version 4.8.0.0
C# 6
.NET Framework 4.5.2 (but have tried building with 4.5.0, 4.0.0, and 4.3.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what this problem was. We were using Selenium for UI tests and the drivers for that were preventing the build from completing for some reason. As far as what part in Selenium was causing this, I'm not sure.